# Why does my companion (Qyzen) have Aim as a primary stat?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

From what the in-game tooltip says about Aim and from what I'm reading online, it's primarily used to increase ranged damage and critical, however, [Qyzen Fess](http://www.torhead.com/npc/cCKwGAf/qyzen-fess) doesn't use ranged weapons.  His only Weapon Proficiency is the Techblade.

Why would a Techblade user require Aim?  Why does Qyzen's equipment focus on Aim stats instead of Strength?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qyzen was a 'ranged tank' in the first part of beta, later changed (for some reason) to a melee tank, but a lot of his stuff was AIM related so they just made up a new weapon style 'techblade' that used AIM as primary stat. You'll also notice that for the same reason, you won't find orange techblades like most other weapons. It was changed later in development so it's not fully finished.

Comment: Best answer/explanation by far.  Thank you.

Comment: There are actually [a lot of orange techblades](http://www.torhead.com/items/catg/1/subcatg/13/quality/4).

Answer (score 2):

The Techblade weapon type is specifically tied to the Aim attribute. [(source)](http://www.torhead.com/ability/d8FGToQ/weapon-proficiency-techblade)

Comment: Unfortunately, that tooltip is incorrect.  You can put whatever mods you like into a custom-quality Techblade.  The companion/character determines both what their mainstat is as well as what weapon they use.